# Static import in C++11 (e.g. an enum class)

Tags: c++, c++11, enums, enum-class

My usage of enum class (VS2012):

```
class matrix {
public:
    enum class operation_type {ADD, MULT};
    matrix(operation_type op);
...
}
```

and in another fragment I use

```
matrix* m = new matrix(matrix::operation_type::ADD);
```

If the names are long, this becomes very messy.

**Is it possible to somehow import the enum values** so that I could write:

```
matrix* m = new matrix(ADD);
```

The same regards nested classes - can I import them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No**, it is not possible.

You cannot omit the `operation_type` part, because you have made this a *scoped* enumeration (and that is what scoped enumeration are all about). If you want to avoid it, you have to make it an unscoped `enum` (removing the `class` keyword).

Besides, outside of `matrix` you cannot import a member name through a `using` declaration as if `matrix` was a namespace. Moreover, per Paragraph 7.3.3/7 of the C++11 Standard:

> A using-declaration shall not name a scoped enumerator.

Comment: you mean if I have `class A {public: class B {} }` then I can't write `using A::B`, right?

Comment: @JoshuaMN: I believe you can only do that if you write it inside a subclass of `A`.